# Is there a lighting code restricting where lights can be placed?

Tags: lighting, code-compliance, light

I am having a new home built in New Brighton, MN, USA. We went over the plans on where we would like our lights, outlets, switches to be placed throughout the home. I asked them to place a light in a different position in the storage area of the garage.

See the image below. The red X's indicate where the lights are currently placed. A few months ago I asked them to move the red X in the storage area closer to the main part of the garage (where the blue X is located). At first, no one objected to this plan. However, we just did a walk through of the home before they install the drywall. I was told that they cannot move the light because of "code".

I've tried searching but cannot find any code restricting where lights can be placed. Does anyone know of such code for my area or in general?

[image: model floor plan]

Comment: It looks to me like the current position is closer to the middle of the storage area than the position you want to change it to. Could that be a basis for a code requirement?  Maybe you could get them to add a box at the new position and have that in addition to the current one. If not, unless this is a low ceiling, it would be easy to add a box there later which would be on the same switch as the current  location.

Comment: Yeah that's a huge area (23' long) for a single light. I'd at least leave that one where it is and install another light where you indicated (which, btw, should be less work than actually removing the old one). I recently insulated and drywalled my 19x21' garage, and have 2x 100W LED bulbs in the middle (about where yours are), 2x 3' flourescent fixtures at the back and put nothing in the front above where the door opens, but in retrospect I wish I had put two more there (6 lights total) and just used the 100W LED bulbs everywhere. You have twice the space with half the fixtures ;)

Comment: I accidentally posted this question as a guest. But, I actually don't want the light there because I plan on having a golf hitting net in that area. I will be standing directly underneath where the light is currently. I am concerned about height clearance when I swing a golf club. I plan on putting a lamp or some other light in the storage area.

Comment: See if they will rough in another box where you want it. While you are in your golfing phase you could cap the wires and put a blank cover plate on it. When you are finished golfing or when you sell this house someone can put a fixture where it should be.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any restrictions off the top of my head other than in closets and bathrooms. I would make them show you the code reference sounds like someone missed the change and is two lazy to do it they way you wanted it.

Answer (score 1):

As of NEC 2005 (NEC is updated every 3 yrs.), (210.70A2b) requires a "switched light in the garage, hall & stairs"; as well as, "a switched lighting outlet on exterior side of all grade level doors except garage vehicle door."  There is no mention of spacing, specific location, minimum lumens, or etc.